# Firefox Web Extension “management” API not working

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am quite new to Firefox Web Extension development but I wanted to give it a try. I am playing around with some basic examples but I cannot get the “management” API to work.

This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "description": "my demo",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Demo",
  "version": "1.0",

   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["first_try.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "management",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["analysis.js"]
  }
}
```

This is my background script code:

```
var management =  browser.management;
console.log(management);
management.getAll(function (apps) {     
    console.log(apps);
});
```

I also tried the following snippet but it didn't change anything

```
management.getAll().then((extensions) => {
for (let extension of extensions) {
  console.log(extension);
}
```

This is the output when I run the extension:

```
Object { getAll: Getter, get: Getter, getSelf: Getter, uninstallSelf: Getter, IconInfo: Getter, ExtensionDisabledReason: Getter, ExtensionType: Getter, ExtensionInstallType: Getter, ExtensionInfo: Getter }

TypeError: management.getAll is not a function
```

I get the smae error even if I remove the "managment" line from the permissions.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? `management.getAll()` is [only available from Firefox 55](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management#Browser_compatibility), which is currently in Beta. Even then, it only [returns "theme"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/getAll#Browser_compatibility) [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/ExtensionInfo#Type) add-ons, which does not sound that useful.

Comment: Thanks. I am using. Firefox 54. Indeed only returning "theme" types does not sound very helpfull.